# Solve w/ the reduction of order method: $(1-x^2)y''+2xy'-2y = 0\space\space(-1 < x < 1);\space y_{1}(x)=x $

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

In the problem below, how would I use the **reduction of order** method to find a second linearly independent solution y<sub>2</sub>?

$$(1-x^2)y''+2xy'-2y = 0\space\space(-1 < x < 1);\space y_{1}(x)=x $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $y_1(x) = c_0 x$ obeys the ODE. Now using the variation of constants method due to Lagrange, substituting $y_1 = c_0(x) x$ into de ODE we obtain

$$
x(1-x^2)c_0''(x)+2c_0'(x) = 0
$$

which can be arranged as

$$
\frac{c_0''(x)}{c_0'(x)} = -\frac{2}{x(1-x^2)} = \left(\ln c_0'(x)\right)' 
$$

integrating we get

$$
\ln c_0'(x) = c_1 - 2\left(\ln x-\frac 12\ln(1-x^2)\right)
$$

and

$$
c_0'(x) = c_2\left(\frac{1-x^2}{x^2}\right)
$$

integrating again we obtain

$$
c_0(x) = c_3-c_2\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)
$$

and thus

$$
y(x) = \left( c_3-c_2\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)\right)x
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$$y=xg(x)$$
Which yeilds
$$x(1-x^2){g_2}+2g_1=0$$